# Не собирается docker

Tags: golang, docker

Пытаюсь собрать контейнер docker. Делаю все по инструкции, но получаю ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?
Первый раз работаю с Docker и пока что не знаю где искать траблу. Прикладываю скрины ошибок и процесса сборки.
Проблема возникает конкретно в строке RUN docker-файла. Ругается на то, что в GOPATH есть .mod файл, а его не должно быть. Прикладываю также содержимое GOPATH. Там нет .mod файла, разве что он рекурсивно находит его в папке проекта в src. Но без mod файла не получится разрабатывать приложение, так как разработка идёт через модули.
Спасибо
[image: Процесс сборки+GOPATH]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно компилятор ругается. Вы собираете ваше приложение в образе `golang`. В этом образе `GOPATH=/go`, и текущий каталог тоже `/go`. Инструкция `COPY ./ ./` копирует ваше приложение в `/go` образа, а инструкция `RUN go build .` запускает сборку тоже в `/go`, то есть внутри `$GOPATH`

Вам нужно собирать в другом каталоге. Например, добавьте в начало инструкцию `WORKDIR`, чтобы все последующие инструкции запускались в другом каталоге:

```
FROM golang:1.21.4

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN go build -o ./test .
CMD ["./test"]
```

Работает, проверено.

Но я предлагаю вам пойти дальше и уменьшить образ, удалив из итогового образа исходные файлы и промежуточные файлы сборки. Для этого используйте фичу multi-stage build.

```
FROM golang:1.21.4 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN go build -o ./test .

FROM alpine:latest as runner
# добавить glibc для приложения
RUN apk add gcompat
WORKDIR /app
# Скопировать собранный бинарник, "забыв" все остальные файлы из builder
COPY --from=builder /app/test ./
CMD ["./test"]
```

Этап `builder` использует большой образ `golang` для сборки приложения. Затем этот образ выбрасывается и заменяется суперкомпактным `alpine`. Единственное, в `alpine` нужно добавить `glibc`, с которой слинкован образ, собранный в `builder`, без этого не запустится.

Из `builder` нужно взять бинарник, собранный командой `go build`. Если ваше приложение использует какие-либо ресурсы, их тоже нужно перенести в рабочий образ.